# Why is there a memory leak when I am using unique_ptr?

Tags: vector, memory-leaks, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I declare:

```
template<class T>
using UniquePntr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

I have a base class, Behavior with a virtual destructor.

```
class Behavior {
public:

  ...

  virtual ~Behavior() {
  }

};
```

I derive classes from Behavior, and some of these classes contain a vector of pointers to other objects derived from Behavior stored in:

```
vector<UniquePntr<Behavior>> stepInstances;
```

Sometimes I explicitly delete the instances with:

```
  void reset() {
    const bool flag = true;
    if (flag) {
      stepInstances.clear();
    } else {
      stepNum=0;
      for(UniquePntr<Behavior> &p : stepInstances) {
        p.reset();
      }
    }
  }
```

If flag is true, valgrind shows a memory leak.  When flag is false, there are no issues.  I confirmed with print statements that the destructors on derived classes are not called when flag is true.  I can't see why.  I am sure clearing a vector of unique_ptr should delete the owned objects.  Any ideas ?